error CS0311: The type 'MauiApp1.Views.CallPage' cannot be used as type parameter
I want to integrate and adapt the code from here for my project https://github.com/AlphaTechstudios/Xamarin-Forms/tree/master/ChatApp.Mobile. Except I'm getting these errors for all pages.
I use .net maui with.net 7.
error CS0311: The type 'MauiApp1.Views.CallPage' cannot be used as type parameter 'TView' in the generic type or method 'IContainerRegistryExtensions.RegisterForNavigation<TView, TViewModel>(IContainerRegistry, string)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MauiApp1.Views.CallPage' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'.
using MauiApp1.Services.Core;
using MauiApp1.Services.Interfaces;
using MauiApp1.ViewModels;
using MauiApp1.Views;
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Unity; 

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication 
    {
        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) 
        {

        }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();

            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();

            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ChatRoomPage, ChatRoomPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<FriendsPage, FriendsPageViewModel>();

            containerRegistry.Register<IChatService, ChatService>();
            containerRegistry.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
            containerRegistry.Register<ISessionService, SessionService>();
            containerRegistry.Register<IUsersService, UsersService>();

            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PrivateChatPage, PrivateChatPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<IncomeCallPage, IncomeCallPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CallPage, CallPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.Views.CallPage"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com" 
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Views"
             Title="CallPage">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="50,*,60,30">
        <views:GenericWebView x:Name="CallWebView"       
                 Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
             <!--prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"-->
        <!--<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="#CCC"
                 Grid.RowSpan="4"
                 IsVisible="false"/>-->
        <Frame Margin="0"
               Padding="0"
               IsVisible="false">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 50,50">
                <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                   Text="Someone is calling..."
                   Padding="0"
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="1"
                       HeightRequest="25"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Source="outline_call.png"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="2"
                       HeightRequest="25"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Source="end_call.png"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"
                     Margin="0,0,10,0"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   CornerRadius="50"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   WidthRequest="60"
                   Padding="1"
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding IsAudioActive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=#00FFFFFF|#80CCCCCC}"
                   BorderColor="LightGray"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ImageButton Source="mic_off.png"
                             Margin="10"
                             CornerRadius="50"
                             HeightRequest="50"
                             WidthRequest="50"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center"
                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             Clicked="ToggleMicClick"/>
            </Frame>

            <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   CornerRadius="50"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   WidthRequest="60"
                   Padding="1"
                   BackgroundColor="#CC0000"
                   BorderColor="LightGray"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ImageButton Source="end_call.png"
                             Margin="10"
                             CornerRadius="50"
                             HeightRequest="50"
                             WidthRequest="50"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center"
                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             Clicked="EndCallClick"
                             Command="{Binding EndCallClick}"/>
            </Frame>

            <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   CornerRadius="50"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   WidthRequest="60"
                   Padding="1"
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding IsVideoActive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=#007E33|#80CCCCCC}"
                   BorderColor="LightGray"
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ImageButton Source="video_call.png"
                             Margin="10"
                             CornerRadius="50"
                             HeightRequest="50"
                             WidthRequest="50"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center"
                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             Clicked="ToggelCameraClick"/>
            </Frame>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

using MauiApp1.Services.Interfaces;
using MauiApp1.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace MauiApp1.Views;

public partial class CallPage
{
    private CallPageViewModel callPageViewModel;
    public CallPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var urlSource = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.UrlWebViewSource();
        string baseUrl = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DependencyService.Get<IWebViewService>().GetContent();
        urlSource.Url = baseUrl;
        CallWebView.Source = urlSource;
        callPageViewModel = BindingContext as CallPageViewModel;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var response = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
            if (response != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
            }
        }

        var statusMic = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
        if (statusMic != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var response = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
            if (response != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
            }
        }
        await Connect();
    }

    private async Task Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            await CallWebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"init('{callPageViewModel.CurrentUser.ID}');");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await CallWebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"startCall('{callPageViewModel.Friend.ID}');");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    }

    private async void ToggleMicClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        callPageViewModel.IsAudioActive = !callPageViewModel.IsAudioActive;
        await CallWebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"toggleAudio('{callPageViewModel.IsAudioActive.ToString().ToLower()}');");
    }

    private void EndCallClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndCall();
    }

    private async void ToggelCameraClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        callPageViewModel.IsVideoActive = !callPageViewModel.IsVideoActive;
        await CallWebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"toggleVideo('{callPageViewModel.IsVideoActive.ToString().ToLower()}');");
    }

    private void EndCall()
    {
        CallWebView.Source = "about:blank";
    }
}

I tried modifying elements in the pages to see if that was the cause of the problem.

You haven't shown anything about how CallPage is declared.

It's done, I added for CallPage

It looks like you've got at least some code still referring to Xamarin as opposed to MAUI. I'd look at where IContainerRegistryExtensions comes from... if that's Xamarin-specific, you need the MAUI equivalent.

How can I find the equivalent? You know it?

No, I don't even know where it comes from. You should be able to find that out though - aside from anything else, pressing F12 with your cursor on RegisterForNavigation should be a starting point.

(If it's in Prism, then using Prism.Maui seems like a pretty obvious first thing to try.)

Hello @Official,
I've reviewed your code and identified an issue. To properly bind your ViewModel with the View, you should replace (callPageViewModel = BindingContext as CallPageViewModel;) with (callPageViewModel = new CallPageViewModel();) and then test to see if it resolves the problem.
